# Localization in a GWT multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, gwt, internationalization

I have a GWT maven webapp project that used to consist of a single module. As a result of requirements evolution, I need to extract some of the code into separate modules to make them reusable. So far, this process was going well until I decided to extract localization code in order to use it in another project.

What I have is `MyAppConstants` and `MyAppMessages` interfaces with corresponding `.properties` files, which are used in client code by means of `GWT.create()`. I moved them to separate module, added `Localization.gwt.xml` file and specified the following inside `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <module>com.myapp.Localization</module>
        <!-- Do not compile source files, just check them -->
        <validateOnly>true</validateOnly>
        <!-- i18n -->
        <i18nConstantsBundle>com.myapp.client.MyAppConstants_ru</i18nConstantsBundle>
        <i18nMessagesBundle>com.myapp.client.MyAppMessages_ru</i18nMessagesBundle>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>i18n</goal>
                <goal>resources</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In main application module I simply inherited `Localization.gwt.xml`. As a result of compilation, I can see that `.cache.html` files do not contain localized constants and messages (they look like `\u0410\u043B...`) which they used to have. I suppose this happens because GWT compiler doesn't see source files (f.e., `com.myapp.client.MyAppConstants_ru.java`) in `.generated` folder where they normally reside after successful execution of `i18n` phase of maven plugin. Instead, they can be found in `localization.jar`.

I feel like I'm missing something because this doesn't seem like a non-trivial task to solve. What would be the proper way of handling such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, in order to have proper localization, you need to have `.properties` files in classpath at the time of GWT compilation. Initially, I filtered them out of `localization.jar` because their presence caused GWT compilation failures with messages like this:

> Rebind result 'com.myapp.client.MyAppConstants_ru' must be a class

I digged into `gwt-dev.jar` contents and found out that compiler actually checks presence of localization properties files in classpath to determine bind results.

So my problem was solved by:

- removing `<goal>i18n</goal>` and corresponding configuration in `localization` module
- making sure `.properties` files make their way to `localization.jar`

Which makes me wonder, what's the use of `i18n` goal of `gwt-maven-plugin`?